# Java Android Data Binding ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, binding

I have problem with list view in data binding because I don't know how to set custom `ArrayAdapter` in view model, and how to add `onItemClick` listener in view model. Someone can show how to do this? Internet have really little information about this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the adapter for the ListView. `R.id.listview` must refer to your ListView defined in the Layout obviously and `R.layout.listviewrow` to a layout that a row should have. Furthermore add a new Instance of onItemClickListener to the ListView.

```
MyCustomArrayAdapter adapter = new MyCustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listviewrow);
ListView lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           //perform desired action here
        }
    } );
```

The Adapter itself should look something like this:

```
public class MyCustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    public MyCustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    public MyCustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(resource, null);
        }

        Item item = getItem(position);

        if (item != null) {
            TextView tvFirstName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstName);
            TextView tvLastName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lastName);

        if (tvFirstName != null) {
            tvFirstName.setText(item.getFirstName());
        }

        if (tvLastName != null) {
            tvLastName.setText(item.getLastName);
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```